# Docker, the proxy setting unworks and fails to pull a image like hello-world

Tags: docker, proxy, connection

I have install docker in my ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2(win10) fellow the offical doc on :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

After the installation, I run: `docker run hello-world` for test. I receive the follow msg:

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
> See 'docker run --help'.

I am in a enviroment of my company, which would only visit "www.google.com" through a proxy.
In fact, through my setting proxy, I could get a

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK

when running

```
curl -I www.google.com
```

While on the docker, I set up the proxy by creating the "https-proxy.conf" file in the direction of `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`.

And write the context:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://usrname:psw@proxy.xxx.com:xxxx"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://usrname:psw@proxy.xxx.com:xxxx"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,.xxx.com"
```

After that I just run:`systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker` by order.
Then I check if the proxy works, running `systemctl show --property=Environment docker`
I get a result as:

```
Environment=NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,.xxx.com
```

Another two setting seem do not become effective. I have no idea what's wrong with the proxy setting while I want to make it aviable for docker. Would any one help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add below to /etc/default/docker file, then restart docker

```
export http_proxy="your proxy url""
export http_proxy="your proxy url"
export no_proxy="localhost"
```